# Fill R matrix based on the list with row IDs

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix in R with ids as rownames and colnames. I also have a list of ids. For rownames which are not in id list I need to fill row with NA.

```
id_list <- c(1079, 1081, 1082, 1083)

mat <- matrix(1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

rownames(mat) <- colnames(mat) <- c(1079, 1080, 1081, 1082, 1083)
```

Desired result:

|  | 1079 | 1080 | 1081 | 1082 | 1083 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1079 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1080 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 1081 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1082 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1083 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine the rows in the matrix whose names are not included in `id_list` by using the expression `!rownames(mat) %in% id_list`.
This creates a logical vector where `TRUE` indicates row names that are absent from `id_list`.
Next, use this vector to index those specific rows in the matrix and assign NA to all their elements.

```
mat[!rownames(mat) %in% id_list, ] <- NA
mat
```

```
     1079 1080 1081 1082 1083
1079    1    1    1    1    1
1080   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
1081    1    1    1    1    1
1082    1    1    1    1    1
1083    1    1    1    1    1
```